# Running different objects in IDEA - Scala

Tags: scala, object, intellij-idea

I have 3 different objects that I've written in IDEA, labelled PartA, PartB, and PartC. However, when I attempt to run any of these objects, the only one that gives me the option to run is PartB. When I right click on the code for PartA and PartC, I have no option to run them. Only PartB has the option to run. What's going on here, and how can I fix it so I can run the different objects I have written?

Edit: Sorry, first time posting a question here. Here's the code I have written.

```
    object PartB extends App {
    def easter(Y:Int): Int = {
        val N = Y - 1900
        val A = N - (N/19) * 19
        val B = (7 * A + 1) / 19
        val C = 11 * A + 4 - B
        val M = C - (C / 29) * 29
        val Q = N / 4
        val S = N + Q + 31 - M
        val W = S - (S / 7) * 7
        val DATE = 25 - M - W
      return DATE
    }

  println("Enter a year: ")
    val year = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()

  val date = easter(year)
  var easter_day : String = ""

  if (date == 0) {
    easter_day = "March, 31"
  } else if (date < 0) {
    easter_day = "March, " + (31 + year)
  } else {
    easter_day = "April, " + date
  }

  println("In " + year + ", Easter is on " + easter_day + ".")
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

object PartC {
  def ack(m:Int, n:Int) : Int = {
    if (m == 0) {
      return n + 1
    } else if (n == 0) {
      return ack(m - 1, 1)
    } else {
      return ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1))
    }
  }

  println("Enter a value for m: ")
    val m = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()

  println("Enter a value for n: ")
    val n = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()

  println(ack(m, n))
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code? Also, it's preferred to define `main` method instead to put code in the object directly. Maybe this would help?

Comment: it's always better to add some code.

Comment: Adding a main worked it out, thanks! Still getting used to Scala so I thought I didn't need a main function, like python.

Comment: I personnaly prefer the "extends App" solution, but I suppose it's a matter of taste. @JayTucker if you're not familiar with SO, please consider accepting the answer you got :-)

Answer (score 1):

`PartB extends App`, but `PartC` doesn't. Presumably `PartA` doesn't either.

> [The App trait can be used to quickly turn objects into executable programs... the whole class body becomes the “main method”.](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/App.html)

So `PartB` defines a `main` method.